# Failed to Connect to the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator running Docker using Mongo

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm having trouble using the Azure Cosmos Emulator running in Docker. When run my app, I get the following error while trying to connect to the DB:

```
connection error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:10255] on first connect [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:10255
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
```

#### Setup

As per the [Running on Docker instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-docker), I pulled the image and ran

```
md %LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator\bind-mount

docker run --name azure-cosmosdb-emulator --memory 2GB --mount "type=bind,source=%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator\bind-mount,destination=C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\bind-mount" --interactive --tty -p 8081:8081 -p 8900:8900 -p 8901:8901 -p 8902:8902 -p 10250:10250 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 -p 10255:10255 -p 10256:10256 -p 10350:10350 mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/windows/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

#### Config

1. I've tried several different connection strings with no luck, the main one I'm using is:

```
mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

2. I am able to access the explorer on https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html so the emulator is running.
3. I'm using mongoose in app

Answer (score 3):

After some frustrated head scratching, I found the solution! Based off the [Docker container page](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator/) for the emulator instructions, you need to run the following docker command:

```
docker run --name azure-cosmosdb-emulator --memory 2GB --mount "type=bind,source=%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator\bind-mount,destination=C:\CosmosDB.Emulator\bind-mount" --interactive --tty -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_MONGODB_ENDPOINT=true -p 8081:8081 -p 8900:8900 -p 8901:8901 -p 8902:8902 -p 10250:10250 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 -p 10255:10255 -p 10256:10256 -p 10350:10350 mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/windows/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

The important change is the addition of: `-e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_MONGODB_ENDPOINT=true`

---

Update:

I have since found this enables the 3.2 protocol, for the 3.6 protocol you will need to use: `-e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_MONGODB_COMPUTE_ENDPOINT=true`

More discussion is available in this [github discussion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47982), where someone also pointed out that the Gremlin & Casandra options are:

- `-e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_GREMLIN_ENDPOINT=true`
- `-e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT=true`

Comment: I am trying to run the emulator in Mac like ```docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 -p 10255:10255  -m 3g --cpus=2.0 --namtest-linux-emulator -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=127.0.0.1 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_MONGODB_ENDPOINT=true -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_MONGODB_COMPUTE_ENDPOINT=true -it mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator ``` to access cosmos emulator through mongo API. But it doesnt work. Any help

Comment: What connection string are you using?

Comment: Seems to be limitation with cosmos linux emulator, Mongo APIs are not supported.