# How start azure-cosmosdb-emulator in Docker with the parameter EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6

Tags: mongodb, docker, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to run my **azure-cosmosdb-emulator** container inside docker which I was able to do it successfully. I have followed the steps mentioned in the link [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-on-docker-windows?tabs=cli)

But,

I want to start the emulator with the option **EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6**. The above help page does not say about "How to pass EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found the asnswer through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252095/failed-to-connect-to-the-azure-cosmos-db-emulator-running-docker-using-mongo but still have other errors popping up now.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates#export-emulator-certificate did you do?